# Error on running a brandnew VUE JS Hello.word App

Tags: vue.js, npm

I'm trying to run my first app  .  I've created it from CLI:   vue create hello-world
When I try to start the app  with the CLI : `npm run serve`   the app runs. 
When I try to start the app  with the CLI : `npm run dev` the app returns me the follow error.

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator\hello-world> npm install -g npm@latest
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\npx -> C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npx-cli.js
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\npm -> C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
+ npm@6.13.7
added 434 packages from 860 contributors in 14.601s
PS C:\Users\Administrator\hello-world> npm run dev
npm ERR! missing script: dev

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-12T16_06_26_201Z-debug.log
```

This is my packagejson:

```
{
    "name": "hello-world",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
        "build": "vue-cli-service build",
        "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"

    },
    "dependencies": {
        "core-js": "^3.6.4",
        "vue": "^2.6.11"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.2.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.2.0",
        "@vue/cli-service": "^4.2.0",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
        "eslint": "^6.7.2",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.1.2",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "root": true,
        "env": {
            "node": true
        },
        "extends": [
            "plugin:vue/essential",
            "eslint:recommended"
        ],
        "parserOptions": {
            "parser": "babel-eslint"
        },
        "rules": {}
    },
    "browserslist": [
        "> 1%",
        "last 2 versions"
    ]
}

    PS C:\Users\Administrator
```

I also tried to put the new line into my package.json :  `"dev": "vue-cli-service dev"`
but I get  this error:

```
> vue-cli-service dev

 ERROR  command "dev" does not exist.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! hello-world@0.1.0 dev: `vue-cli-service dev`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the hello-world@0.1.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-12T16_23_48_785Z-debug.log
```

Comment: What are you expecting `npm run dev` to do?

Comment: I'm just following a web tutorial and it tells me to run this command.

Comment: Is the tutorial using a recent version of CLI? I suspect you just need to use `npm run serve` instead. Without knowing what `dev` is supposed to do it's difficult to speculate further.

Answer (score 1):

The [npm run](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server) command execute a instruction that you already defined on your script section inside your package.json file.

In simple words, the command defined on the script section of your package.json file will be executed on your terminal command line.

You can define custom scripts in this section. You did this and when you typed: `npm run dev`, the script defined on the scripts section on your package.json file was executed as `vue-cli-service dev`. But the instruction `dev` does not exist in [vue-cli-service](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/cli-service.html#using-the-binary).
The command that you are looking for might be `vue-cli-service serve`, which will start a [webpack dev server](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server) instance and it's basically the same of `npm run serve`.